# How to bypass or completely ignore the following cookie so that the code can function with Microsoft edge instead of Internet Explorer?

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a C# code that connects to a list of defined APIs and retrieves the specific values. However, this code relies heavily on wininet.dll and its functions, specifically InternetGetCookieEx, and since Internet Explorer has expired, the code will no longer function. Can I bypass the IE cookies?

I have made a controllers folder which contains: StaticStrings.cs, WebAPI.cs, and WebNav.cs

StaticStrings.cs defines the APIs.

WebNav.cs contains the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal sealed class NativeMethods
{
    #region enums

    public enum ErrorFlags
    {
        ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122,
        ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87,
        ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259
    }

    public enum InternetFlags
    {
        INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 8192, //Requires IE 8 or higher   
        INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY = 131072,
        INTERNET_FLAG_RESTRICTED_ZONE = 16
    }

    #endregion

    #region DLL Imports

    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity, SecurityCritical, DllImport("wininet.dll", EntryPoint = "InternetGetCookieExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    internal static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx([In] string Url, [In] string cookieName, [Out] StringBuilder cookieData, [In, Out] ref uint pchCookieData, uint flags, IntPtr reserved);

    #endregion
}

namespace WeeklySchedule.Contollers
{
    public class FullWebBrowserCookie : WebBrowser
    {

        [SecurityCritical]
        public static string GetCookieInternal(Uri uri, bool throwIfNoCookie)
        {
            uint pchCookieData = 0;
            string url = UriToString(uri);
            uint flag = (uint)NativeMethods.InternetFlags.INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY;

            //Gets the size of the string builder   
            if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, null, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                pchCookieData++;
                StringBuilder cookieData = new StringBuilder((int)pchCookieData);

                //Read the cookie   
                if (NativeMethods.InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, cookieData, ref pchCookieData, flag, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    DemandWebPermission(uri);
                    return cookieData.ToString();
                }
            }

            int lastErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

            if (throwIfNoCookie || (lastErrorCode != (int)NativeMethods.ErrorFlags.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS))
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(lastErrorCode);
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static void DemandWebPermission(Uri uri)
        {
            string uriString = UriToString(uri);

            if (uri.IsFile)
            {
                string localPath = uri.LocalPath;
                new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, localPath).Demand();
            }
            else
            {
                new WebPermission(NetworkAccess.Connect, uriString).Demand();
            }
        }

        private static string UriToString(Uri uri)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
            }

            UriComponents components = (uri.IsAbsoluteUri ? UriComponents.AbsoluteUri : UriComponents.SerializationInfoString);
            return new StringBuilder(uri.GetComponents(components, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped), 2083).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

WebAPI.cs contains the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using WeeklyScheduleModels;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WeeklySchedule.Contollers
{
    class WebAPI
    {
        public string GetNorderTimeExpensebyNo(string norderNo)
        {


            return "OK";
        }




        public string GetNorderDbIDfromNo(string norderNo)
        {

            return "";
        }


        public double GetBookedHours(string subOrderNo)
        {
            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlNCert), false);
          

            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            string uri = "";

            double totalHours = 0.0;
            uri = StaticStrings.NOrderTimeExpenseAPI + subOrderNo;
            var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);
            NCertTimeExpenseMain ntem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NCertTimeExpenseMain>(response);
            foreach (OracleHour oh in ntem.oracleHours)
            {
                totalHours += oh.hours;
            }

            return totalHours;
        }

        //To get the status of the project from Ncert
        public string GetOrderStatus(string subOrderNo)
        {
            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlNCert), false);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            string uri = "";

            //double totalHours = 0.0;
            uri = StaticStrings.OrderStatusAPI + subOrderNo+'?';
            var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);
            
            RootObject status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);
            
            string currentstatusofproject = status.statusDescription;
            return currentstatusofproject;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to replace the WebNav.cs code with the following, however it still does not work.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WeeklySchedule.Contollers
{
    public class FullWebBrowserCookie : WebBrowser
    {

        //[SecurityCritical]
        public static string GetCookieInternal(Uri uri, bool throwIfNoCookie)
        {
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                cookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
            }

            var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(uri);
            if (cookies.Count == 0 && throwIfNoCookie)
            {
                throw new Exception("No Cookies found for the given URI");
            }

            return string.Join(";", cookies.OfType<Cookie>().Select(c => c.Name + "=" + c.Value));
      }
}
```

Comment: InternetGetCookieEx and WebBrowser control will only work in IE. But WebBrowser control will remain in-support after IE retirement (if you want to keep using this code). If you would like to interact with Chromium browsers, you can try CefSharp.

Comment: If you're interested in Microsoft's implementation of Chromium browser, have a look at [WebVIew2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) - it's available as a NuGet package.